# Calling IEnumerable.SelectMany

Tags: .net, linq, f#

Given this:

```
open System.Linq

let iota n = [0..(n-1)]
```

the following produces an error:

```
[2; 3; 4].SelectMany(fun n -> iota n)
```

Is there a way to pass function values to `SelectMany`?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the result to a `seq<int>`:

```
[2; 3; 4].SelectMany(fun n -> iota n :> int seq)
```

alternatively you could use `List.collect`:

```
[2; 3; 4] |> List.collect iota
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! Is this a bug? I mean, type wise, isn't a `list<int>` acceptable as a `seq<int>`?

Comment: I submitted a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316324/int-int-list-is-not-compatible-with-type-int-ienumerablea) asking if it's a bug.